# Is there cppcheck plugin available in netbeans

Tags: netbeans-8, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I am using netbeans IDE for development. I want to check my code using cppcheck. Can any one tell me , is cppcheck plugin available for netbeans. If yes how to do that..?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly. There's an open bug for this functionality and the start of a module. 
See https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201680 and https://github.com/johngull/nb-cppcheck

You could always add a custom makefile target that calls cppcheck. Maybe cppcheck's output will be something that NetBeans can recognize and provide hyperlinks to the source lines in the output window.